# Topological Data Analysis (TDA) Mapper for Python

Tags: python, mapper

I am doing a beginner course in Topological Data Analysis and my instructor insists that I use Python for my analysis. I am on Jupyter notebook editor.

I am confused about the Mapper for Python as I can’t find any tutorial documentation about using Mapper for Python on Jupyter notebook. I see clear tutorial guide for Mapper for R and none for Python.

Also, I see that there is a library kmapper on python, is this the same the Mapper that is developed by (Daniel Müllner and Aravindakshan Babu – this is what I have to use.)  I have these all installed on my Anaconda distribution.

If there are any other tools/library for python that you can recommend for Persistent Homology and Simplicial Complex that you can suggest would be great.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. SO is not a general QA platform, but specific for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Kmapper is library for mapper you are right..some other libraries are scikit-tda   Giotto-tda    sakmapper